# Airflow initdb fails due to invalid syntax

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

I am new to Airflow. I followed instructions presented here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYOUbiGtGiU&t=49s

Step 1: Control Panel | Programs and Features | Turn Windows features on or off

Enable : Windows Subsystem for Linux

Step 2: Install Ubuntu from windows store and restart system

Step 3: Install and update PIP

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo apt-add-repository universe

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Step 4: Install airflow

```
export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes

pip install apache-airflow
```

Step 5: Initialize DB

```
airflow initdb
```

After that I got an error:

```
[2019-09-30 17:46:37,888] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 22, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 68, in <module>
    from airflow.www_rbac.app import cached_app as cached_app_rbac
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
  File "/home/barys_rutman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import AppBuilder
  File "/home/barys_rutman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api.manager import OpenApiManager
  File "/home/barys_rutman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Related, RelatedList
  File "/home/barys_rutman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .schema import TableSchemaOpts, ModelSchemaOpts, TableSchema, ModelSchema
  File "/home/barys_rutman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 101
    class TableSchema(ma.Schema, metaclass=TableSchemaMeta):
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [[PyPI]: Apache-AirFlow](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow) is *Python 2(.7)* and *Python 3* compatible
2. It depends (most likely, indirectly) on [[PyPI]: Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/marshmallow-sqlalchemy) (*pip* automatically installs it as a dependency), and uses it (indirectly, via *Flask-AppBuilder*) at runtime
3. *Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy* **requires *Python 3.6+***, meaning that it contains code that it's not compatible with *Python 2* (that you have)

There are a couple of ways to get past this, I think the easiest is **switching to *Python 3*** (and it's also the recommended one, because the sands of time for *Python 2* are running low: [Python 2.7 Countdown](https://pythonclock.org)). 
Modify your some setup steps (I must say those are blind steps, as I didn't test them):

- Install *Python 3* (if not already installed)

  ```bash
  sudo apt-get install python3
  ```
- Install / upgrade *pip3*

  ```bash
  sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  ```
- Use *pip3* to install packages

  ```bash
  pip3 install apache-airflow
  ```
- Modify */usr/bin/python* executable (that *AirFlow* uses) to be a *symlink* to *python3* (back it up first)

  ```bash
  sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.orig
  sudo ln -s python3 /usr/bin/python
  ```
- Carry on with the rest of the steps

Comment: @CristiFati is there any other way we can handle this issue without upgrading python to version 3.x?

Comment: @naveenkumar: Probably it is: downgrade it (and all dependencies) to versions that work with *Python 2*. Maybe some manual code changes will be required. But I'd advice against that. It's always good to be up to date.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run

```
airflow db init
```

Instead of

```
airflow initdb
```